# Cannot convert value of type 'String!' to expected argument type error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, error-handling

I have a public function:

```
public func lastActivityFor(userName: String) -> String { ... }
```

and later I want to call it as:

```
OneLastActivity.lastActivityFor("username")
```

but the last line get error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'String!' to expected argument type 'OneLastActivity'
```

Why it appears if I send to those function String as suggested?(`userName: String`)

Any ideas how can I fix it? If you want more code, just ask me about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create an instance of your class this way:

```
let temp = OneLastActivity()
```

Now you can use it's method:

```
temp.lastActivityFor("username")
```

Or you can directly use it this way:

```
OneLastActivity().lastActivityFor("username")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, I found answer at the same time with you ))
I used `OneLastActivity.sharedInstance.lastActivityFor("username")`

Comment: @DharmeshKheni sir answer this related question please, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733225/cannot-convert-the-value-of-type-string-to-expected-argument-type-string